# Document Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I would like to provide a rationale for choosing a specific dependency in my project (in this case why I chose a particular language-detection library), so am wondering if I can do this in the dependency report section of the site? I looked at the definition of the [dependency element in the pom reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) but there does not seem to be a way to attach any documentation to is.

Does anyone have a good way of documenting such decisions? I would like to put it into the dependencies report if possible as this is where people might reasonably look for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would add it as XML-comment next to the specific dependency.
If you want to explain your choices with a report, just create your [own page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html). The dependency-report has no space for it.

Comment: Thanks, am I alone in thinking this might be a useful thing to actually have in the report? Putting it in as comments is what I currently do but I do not find it satisfying. At the same time, I always felt the generated reports did not do all they could do.

Comment: Apart from the impact of changing the pom.xml model (this recent thread is very interesting: http://maven.markmail.org/thread/atct2fudupym34z6) the pom.xml is not the right document to describe architectural choices. Now imagine the developer that wonders why you are using dep.X, where would he look? Some generated documentation?: then you're lucky. The chance is that he wants to replace the dep. Now he must face your comments right at the source (with link to real docs?) and decide what to do.